# Form selectbox post multiple variables from selection

Tags: php, html, forms

Okay so I have a form with a selectbox to select each State in the US, below is just a portion of the states. Each state has a different email address the form will need to send to. In the form results that are emailed, I need to pass the State's name and the email address.

How it's setup right now, the form works and submits to the correct state's email address, but it also says the user in in State: email1@test.com instead of Alabama.

HTML for selectbox in form.php:

```
<select name="state222"> 
    <option value="email1@test.com" id="Alabama">Alabama</option> 
    <option value="email2@test.com" id="Alaska">Alaska</option> 
    <option value="email3@test.com" id="Arizona">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

partial PHP code for form-submit.php (where the form submits to)

This sets the value of the selected option to $state

```
$state = $_REQUEST['state222'] ;
```

This makes phpmailer send to the selected state's email:

```
$mail->AddAddress($state);
```

Example: if Alaska is selected, $state becomes email2@test.com - How can I also post a different variable to Alaska so I can send what state was selected in the email as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can't with just the `select` alone.  You could get fancy with Javascript and when the select changes update a hidden field with the state name ... but I wouldn't do that.  Why not make the value the state's name or initials, then do a lookup on the back end for the email address?  You could store the email addresses in a database and query them out (`SELECT email FROM state_emails WHERE state='$state'`).  Or (not as nice, not really recommended) just have a static array in the script:

```
$emails = array('AL'=>'email1@test.com', 'AK'=>'email2@test.com' ...);
$email = $emails[$state];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't publicly expose the email addresses in this manner as it is very easy for some one to edit the DOM and insert an email of their choice.  You should create an array which you will use to populate your select field and later reference which select was chosen on the backend.

```
$states = array(array('email' => 'email1@test.com', 'state' => 'Alabama'), array('email' => 'email2@test.com', 'state' => 'Alaska') ...);
```

In your form you can now loop though this array

```
<select name="state222">
<?php foreach($states as $key => $value){ ?>
<option value="<?=$key; ?>"><?=$value['state']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

You will then use the same array on the backend to extact the values needs

```
$state = $states[$_REQUEST['state222']];
```

You now have an array for the state selected with the name `$state['state']` and email `$state['email']`

Comment: I tried this method, i set up the array with 3 states and the selectbox shows 3 results but they are blank. You can see this form at: http://www.uslegalsupport.com/record-retrieval/record-retrieval-request-new/

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working and I'm going to use since the email addresses are already public information.

Backend code: Thanks @NeilGiradi - only thing missing in your code is a $ infront of the second $_POST

```
$state222 = (isset($_POST['state222'])) ? explode('|', $_POST['state222']) : null;
if ($state222) {
    $email = $state222[0];
    $state = $state222[1];
}
```

Frontend:

```
<option value="email1@test.com|Alabama" id="Alabama">Alabama</option>
```